# Python parsing the lines from a file

Tags: python, list, parsing

New to python. I'm reading from file line by line:

```
with open("graph.txt", "r") as f:
    comList = f.readlines()
    print(comList)
    edge_u = [x[0] for x in comList]
    edge_v = [x[1] for x in comList]
```

graph.txt has :

> [(0, 7), (1, 9), (1, 9), (2, 0)]
>
> [(2, 1), (2, 1), (3, 6)]

I was expecting that readlines will parse the file line by line hence will parse the text as a list of list. But its parsing it as List of strings. Hence i;m unable to perform the other two operations. Tried to print edge_u and get to know what its parsing. How to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

```
import ast

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        li = ast.literal_eval(line)
        edge_u = [x[0] for x in li]
        edge_v = [x[1] for x in li]
```

Comment: @user2754673, You don't need to close the file if you open it with `with`.

Comment: Worked Like a charm,, !! Thanks.

Comment: `for line in f.readlines()` is redundant.  `for line if f` is all you need.

Comment: @user2754673, the open file object `f` can be interated directly, yes.

Comment: Upvoted for `ast.literal_eval` instead of direct `eval` being used in other answers.  It's safer.

Answer (score 1):

`file.readlines([size])` returns size bytes worth of lines or all lines as a list of strings. I believe what you want if you want to parse this file would be json.

```
from json import loads

with open('graph.txt', 'r') as fob:
    comList = [loads(line) for line in fob]

edge_u = [x[0] for x in comList]
edge_v = [x[1] for x in comList]
```

Comment: your code isn't working with the given input. `ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: same result unfortunately

Comment: Ahh it must be the the parenthesis throwing json off. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval` but be careful not to catch something exceptional:

```
In [1]: tmp = eval("[(0, 7), (1, 9), (1, 9), (2, 0)]")
In [2]: tmp
Out[2]: [(0, 7), (1, 9), (1, 9), (2, 0)]
```

Otherwise, you have to manually parse the string (what is actually the better solution).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already, you can use `eval`

```
with open("graph.txt","r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        comList = list(map(eval, lines))
        print(type(comList), comList)
        edge_u = [x[0] for x in comList]
        edge_v = [x[1] for x in comList]

print(type(edge_u), edge_u)
print(type(edge_v), edge_v)
```

which produces

```
<class 'list'> [[(0, 7), (1, 9), (1, 9), (2, 0)], [(0, 7), (1, 9), (1, 9), (2, 0)]]
<class 'list'> [(0, 7), (0, 7)]
<class 'list'> [(1, 9), (1, 9)]
```